# how to split and then combine in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "from": ["'a','b'",'c','p,d'],
    "to": ["m",'tom','sky'],
    'other':[1,2,3]
})
```

I want to split each row of `from` column so that each row only contains one item. How to do in a pandas way, so that I obtain as follow?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "from": ["'a'","'b'",'c','p','d'],
    "to": ["m",'m','tom','sky','sky'],
    'other':[1,1,2,3,3]
})
```

I have solved this with `for` loops method. How to do it by a more `pandas-style` method?

Comment: Why does the `other` column change to `1,2,3,4,5`? Is it just sequential?

Comment: sorry it should be 11233.thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `split` then `explode`

```
df['from'] = df['from'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('from')
df
  from   to  other
0  'a'    m      1
0  'b'    m      1
1    c  tom      2
2    p  sky      3
2    d  sky      3
```